# What are the effect of having too many build.gradle.kts files in multimodule

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, multi-module

I would like to know what are the issues of having too many `build.gradle` files due to modularization by features. Here are the example of structure.

```
app
-core
-network
-feature_login
  --ui
  --domain
  --data
-feature_buy
  --ui
  --domain
  --data
-feature_profile
  --ui
  --domain
  --data
_feature_load
  --ui
  --domain
  --data
```

Each module is equipped with its own `build.gradle` file and acts as an independent entity that can expand based on different features. This expansion leads to a significant increase in the number of variants listed. For instance, if there are 30 features, it implies that you would have 90 `build.gradle.kts` files. and also in the build variants.